# Why fromClause in import statement expects string literal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In our previous node.js application(based on ES5), we struggled for having relative paths in *require* statements.

for eg: `var conf = require('../../global/config');`

The issue with the relative paths was bubbled up in code obfuscation. We had to spent considerable time in handling this issue.

With that experience, in our current node.js application(based on ES6), though I'm not sure whether we will obfuscate the code or not I don't want to use relative paths. Hence, I've created a const ROOTDIR in every file and assigned the project's absolute path to it. Then realized that *import* expects only static literals in it's *fromClause*. This makes life difficult by forcing to type(copy/paste) the full path for every *import* or go back using relative paths OR use *require* statement.

[image]

While I'm trying to understand the benefits of using *import* style, I need some help in understanding the following 3 points.

1. What are the advantages of using *import* apart from similar coding style of java/.net?
2. Why *import* is accepting only string literals? It seems it's by design, if so, why?
3. If I want to *import* a module based on some condition, I'll have to go for *require* because I can't use *import* in *if/else* or *switch* statements. Is there any solution/hack for it?

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: you are targeting node.js, aren'n you? `require` is node-specific afaik

Comment: @Psi
Yes, updated the description and tags. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remember that `import` is not currently supported by any environment, including Node.js. So you will probably be using a transpiler, such as Babel, which will assume a CommonJS environment (such as Node) and will fill in using `require`.

`import`, unlike `require` is designed to be statically analysed. That is to say, your code could be analysed *without running it* and it would be possible to tell what modules need to be loaded.

This means that:

1. `import` declarations are hoisted. Wherever they are declared, they effectively exist at the very top of the file.
2. Putting them in blocks is therefore invalid.
3. Putting them in conditionals is therefore invalid.
4. Nothing can exist in the file before the `import` statement, so it is not possible to use any variables (including constants) because they will not exist when the `import` statement is run.

Because the code can be statically analysed, this will in the future ease the process of bundling code. It can be determined exactly what code needs to be included, which will mean that your code could be compiled for distribution more easily. For instance, if a browser requested a JS file that had an `import` statement, the server could see this and package both together. This is a long way off, but it is likely to be the future!

Comment: Yes, I'm using a transpiler (Babel) in our Node.js environment.
Well, I've defined a const in the first line and used it in require. I also have import statements in the same file and this statements are after require statements. It worked without any errors/warnings.
for eg: const ROOTDIR = '/absolute/path/to/project/directory'.
If I understand your reply, it's because of transpiler changing it to ES5 or it's not native ES6 environment. Am I correct?

Comment: @GaneshAdapa Look at the transpiled code! It will give a better explanation than I will.

Comment: thanks a ton. I'll go through the transpiled code today.

Comment: Are there any other features in javascript which are designed to be statically analyzed or is this the only one?

Comment: @tjb Most of JS can be statically analysed. `require` was/is unusual in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `import` and `require` is that with import, you have static dependencies which are resolved by the browser when it *parses* your code, while with require, you have dynamic dependencies which are resolved when Node.js *runs* your code.

The advantage of static imports is that the code is easier for the JavaScript engine to optimize. webpack for example uses it to remove code from imported modules that are not needed to create a smaller bundle (known as tree shaking).

The downside of this is, as you have noted, that you cannot use a dynamic expression after "from", since this can only be resolved at runtime. So this is indeed by design.

There is no "hack" around it, if you must have a dynamic dependency that is resolved at runtime, you need to use "require".